# Python: ValueError: Cannot convert ['CODE', 'P001',] to Excel

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to map a list of names (cols_code) to column_letter in a given range as titles in excel. Here is the list and my code.
I tried the below code and got this error:

`ValueError: Cannot convert ['CODE', 'P001', 'P001', 'P006', 'P006', 'P010', 'P010', 'P025', 'P025', 'P030', 'P030', 'P037', 'P037', 'P050', 'P050', 'P060', 'P060', 'P106', 'P106', 'P045', 'P045', 'P080', 'P080', 'P085', 'P085', 'P095', 'P095', 'P101', 'P101', 'P108', 'P108', 'P120', 'P120'] to Excel`

### How can I map this list (cols_code) to column letters (column_letter)?

`cols_code = ['CODE', 'P001', 'P001', 'P006', 'P006', 'P010', 'P010', 'P025', 'P025', 'P030', 'P030', 'P037', 'P037', 'P050', 'P050', 'P060', 'P060', 'P106', 'P106', 'P045', 'P045', 'P080', 'P080', 'P085', 'P085', 'P095', 'P095', 'P101', 'P101', 'P108', 'P108', 'P120', 'P120']`

```
            for column in range(3, 36):
                column_letter = get_column_letter(column)
                print('col letters', column_letter)
                ws[column_letter + str(fr - 2)] = cols_code
```

---

For instance, if I do this:

`for k, x in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase[0:35]): ws[x + str(fr - 1)] = cols[k]`
it is inserting up to the letter z and I want beyond the letter Z in excel.

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: I am trying to insert cols_code above:into the first row of excel starting from index 3 to 35, which is equivalent to the column_letter above.

Comment: For instance, if I do this:
                for k, x in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase[0:35]):
                     ws[x + str(fr - 1)] = cols[k]
It is inserting up to   # 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' and I want beyond Z.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, which is:

```
for column in range(2, 35):
    column_letter = get_column_letter(column + 1)
    print('col letters', column_letter)
    ws[column_letter + str(fr - 2)] = cols_code[column]
```